# Matrix of linear transformation with respect to standard basis

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $A, B \in M_{2 \times 2}(F)$, for some field F. **Determine** the matrix of the linear operator $T:M_{2 \times 2}(F)\rightarrow M_{2 \times 2}(F) $ given by $T(M)=AMB$, with respect to the standard basis.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Compute the images of the standard basis $\{E_{11},E_{12}, E_{21},E_{22}\}$.